# BroadcastReceiver not working as expected on Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I know this was asked already many times but I can't get this to work. I looked all around Android docs and other sources. I got this activity that has a broadcast receiver variable inside and starts a service as such in the constructor:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compass);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class);
    startService(mIntent);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

I put the service down in the manifest and I am sure it works properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Broadcast receiver is supposed to receive 2 floats from the service periodically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="jemboy.compass" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
        android:name=".GPSTracker"></service>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CompassActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you also show us logs ?

Comment: Why you want to start the BroadcastReceiver. Please put the manifest code here.

Comment: I am not very sure but I guess you need to declare an action in the `Intent` when sending the broadcast and catch the same action in your `IntentFilter`.

Comment: @haike00 This did it, thanks a lot! I didn't see it in any of the docs.. strange. Cheers!

Comment: Please note that if you register your receiver in onResume, it makes sense to unregister it in onPause.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UPDATE_PLAYER)) {
            updateMediaPlayerToggle();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(BUFFERING)) {
            showMediaPlayerBuffering();
        }
    }
};
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter updateIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    updateIntentFilter.addAction(UPDATE_PLAYER);
    updateIntentFilter.addAction(BUFFERING);
    broadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, updateIntentFilter);
}
```

in the service.

```
private void sendUpdatePlayerIntent() {
    Log.d(TAG, "updatePlayerIntent");
    Intent updatePlayerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.UPDATE_PLAYER);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(updatePlayerIntent);
}
```

Example from a media player service.